# Keep user logged into iframe (Django)

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

How can I keep a user logged into my site through iframes on other sites? I am using Django if it helps.

A example of my site being loaded through iframe but doesn’t stay logged in on other sites:

```
<iframe src="https://vidvast.com/videos/user_videos/" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.